# I Can't find the icons dart file

Tags: flutter

Hello please how to access the icons.dart file in flutter ? i can't seem to find it in my packages.
I want to import a customed icon in my project but it doesn't seem to work because i can't find open the icons.dart file please help me

Comment: where is your custom icon located, show some code

Comment: Share the structure of your project, maybe a screenshot!

Answer (score 1):

It's in the `Material` package.
You need to import material: `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`